# Cannondale 24 Speed BIke

Tags: identify-this-bike, cannondale

Anyone knows this bike? I only know this is 24 speed. Model name please?
I know this picture is blurry, but this is the only pic.
[image]

Comment: http://vintagecannondale.com/info/serial_numbers/

Comment: Planning on stealing it? It seems awful nice of the owner to leave it in front of a supermarket unlocked. I hope that if you are planning on stealing it, that the serial number isn't registered on BikeIndex.org or other registry.

Answer (score 1):

The cantilevered dropouts date it from 1989 to 1996, the threadless headset to the later end of that. Based on a quick look through the catalogs [here](http://vintagecannondale.com/catalog/), it looks like a 1995 R700, their entry level triathlon/TT bike, which was sold that year with a polished aluminum frame and black fork. That's making the assumption that it wasn't converted to tri-bars later in it's life. It was had a 2x8 (16 speed) drivetrain, not 3x8 (24 speed), but looking at the picture it looks like you may have miscounted the speeds, I see a double not a triple. The brake levers also don't match, but that's an easy switch so they could be aftermarket.